# Server Socket Program in C for multiple ports

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to listen multiple clients on multiple ports, but I am not able to do the multiple ports. for one port which I'm providing as input is working like a charm but not getting how to provide multiple ports. Please help. Below is my server.c program

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  int listenfd, connfd, n, portnum, fdmax, i, j, nbytes;
  /* master file descriptor list */
  fd_set master;
  /* temp file descriptor list for select() */
  fd_set read_fds;
  pid_t childpid;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buf[MAXLINE];
  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
  FD_ZERO(&master);
  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);


  //Create a socket for the soclet
  //If sockfd<0 there was an error in the creation of the socket
  if ((listenfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
  perror("Problem in creating the socket");
  exit(2);
  }


  //preparation of the socket address
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  scanf("%d", &portnum);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(portnum);
  memset(&(servaddr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

  //bind the socket
  bind (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  //listen to the socket by creating a connection queue, then wait for clients
  listen (listenfd, LISTENQ);

  printf("%s\n","Server running...waiting for connections.");

 /* add the listener to the master set */
 FD_SET(listenfd, &master);
 /* keep track of the biggest file descriptor */
 fdmax = listenfd; /* so far, it's this one*/

 for ( ; ; ) {

 /* copy it */
 read_fds = master;

 if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
 {
    perror("Server-select() error lol!");
    exit(1);
 }
 printf("Server-select() is OK...\n");

 /*run through the existing connections looking for data to be read*/
 for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
 {
    if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
    { /* we got one... */
       if(i == listenfd)
       {
           /* handle new connections */
           clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);

           //accept a connection
           connfd = accept (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

           printf("%s\n","Received request...");

           if ( (childpid = fork ()) == 0 ) {//if it’s 0, it’s child process

           printf ("%s\n","Child created for dealing with client requests");

           //close listening socket
           close (listenfd);

           while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE,0)) > 0)  {
           printf("%s","String received from and resent to the client:");
           puts(buf);
           send(connfd, buf, n, 0);
        }
        if (n < 0)
            printf("%s\n", "Read error");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++)
    {
           /* send to everyone! */
           if(FD_ISSET(j, &master))
           {
                    /* except the listener and ourselves */
                    if(j != listenfd && j != i)
                    {
                         if(send(j, buf, nbytes, 0) == -1)
                         perror("send() error lol!");
                    }
           }
    }
    //close socket of the server
    close(connfd);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: `bind()` binds your socket to the port that you've set in your hint for `&servaddr`. Once you've bound your socket, you cannot receive any data on any port other than the port specified in `servaddr.sin_port = htons(portnum);`

Comment: yes what I have done is I have bind my socket for one port so how to bind my socket for multiple ports ?

Comment: You cannot `bind()` to multiple ports - could you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish? Why can all of your clients not point to the same server:port?

Comment: no its just I'm trying for multiple ports ... all clients can point to the same server thats right ... just trying something different
I was thinking to create different sockets for different ports, ports being input by *argv[] .. but don't know how to proceed

Comment: So yeah sure, you can create multiple sockets and then poll them using `select()` or something similar. Each socket would need to have it's servaddr structure populated with the correct information (including the port). If you're just wanting multiple clients to be able to connect to the same-single server port, that's easy enough too. I'm not sure that's what you're asking though?